# Filter for Content View

Tags: views, 7

[image]

Hi, This my administration page for content view In drupal 7.31. Is there any module for inserting filter for this Custom columns(marked ares) in the top of That table view. I mean search with template id, language or channel

note: template id, language and channel these are my custom fields

Comment: I think the most common solution to this would be custom view with views, views bulk operations and administration views.

Comment: Tx, In views Bulk Operations there are only title,author,status and type field are available.Here I want to add custom filter for my custom fields.

Comment: You can freely modify the views view to add your custom fields.

Comment: I added in views but the problem is it is displayed in other page not this admin->content page. I want that options in admin->content page only

Comment: Administration views can replace your admin/content page with editable view.

Comment: Right Here I add one module for displaying my custom fields in table view, admin views not working along with this module.

Comment: Yes those modules dont support each other, views handles additional columns differently and with much better extensibility. I took a look at extra_columns module source code and it seems theres no prebuild support for sorting there and you might have to code your own extension module for that.